# How to determine what a shortcut calls in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts

I thought this would be trivial, however I cannot figure it out.

I am using Abbyy FineReader, which comes with a bunch of automated tasks that can be started from the Start Menu. I have created a new automated task, and I would like to invoke it from the start menu like the others.

[image]

However when I click properties on a shortcut, under the Shortcut tab, Target is grayed out and it doesn't contain anything that lets me edit it. Hence I cannot figure out how the existing shortcuts are working. I assume its just calling an exe with some arguments...

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of what I see]

Comment: Its probably linked to a dll used by Abby, you could use Process Monitor to capture what is being accessed when you click that link...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Thanks that worked to determine what the shortcut did. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably linked to a dll or other file used by Abby, you could use Process Monitor to capture what is being accessed when you click that link.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645